# Handling a form with Spring MVC without using the Spring <form:form> tag?

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc

Is it possible to handle a form using Spring annotation `@ModelAttribute` without using the Spring tag `<form:form...>`.  I saw this [way to do](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/) but it seems complex with using Thymeleaf (I don't know anything about it).

Spring is supposed to be a non-intrusive framework so is there an alternate solution to my problem?

Comment: What are you using in place of Thymeleaf ?

Comment: Nothing else, just using a simple JSP page with JSTL and EL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you build your form using Spring tags, it will be converted to HTML. Run your project and check the source code of your JSP site. Spring tags just make things a bit easier for a coder. For example

```
<form:form modelAttribute="newUser" action="/addUser" method="post">
   <form:input path="firstName" />
   <form:input path="lastName" />
   <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form:form>
```

will be converted to HTML

```
<form id="newUser" action="/addUser" method="post">
   <input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" value="" />
   <input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" value="" />
   <button type="submit">Add</button>
</form>
```

In Controller you add a data transfer object (DTO) to Model, for example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView homePage() {
   ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
   model.addObject("newUser", new User());
   model.setViewName("index");
   return model;
}
```

and receive the form data

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addUser(
        @ModelAttribute("newUser") User user) { ... }
```

Using Spring tags is totally optional as long as the naming of the form fields is exactly the same as in your bean object (here User class) and model.

Comment: So we can totally ignore the Spring tags and just using the value of the "id" attribute (here : "newUser") to bind the form with its POJO in the controller side! I'm right?

Comment: Yes, you got it right.That's how it works. Many input attributes are even easier and shorter to write in basic HTML like required="required" => required etc. In more complex forms like select - option the spring tag version is more compact.

Comment: In HTML version all the basic input attributes (id, name, type, value) have to be there. You may leave nothing out. Otherwise it won't always work.

Comment: What do you mean "Otherwise it won't always work", is it not always work in the controller side with this way to do?

Comment: Spring tags seem really compact but I already realized my form exclusively in HTML version but I would handle it with a Spring controller, that why I am wondering if it is possible without modify my form.

Comment: I meant every form element must have at least id, name and value to work properly. You have to write "perfect" HTML in Spring :)

Comment: Okay. But "value" should be optional or not ?

Comment: It's a good way to post some value to every field of "User" pojo when you are learning these things. Empty "" is also a value. If you send no value at all (no value=""), it may cause an error (exception), but I won't explain it here.

Comment: I plan to use "value" to display the information entered by the user when the form is not correct.

Comment: Turned out it will work with omitting some parameters. However, it is required you add setters to your POJO.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSp as suggested in the comment section above.
First you must add the following depency to your pom (or its equivalent for gradle)

```
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>2.4</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Also, your jsp's should be placed inside your web-inf folder. 
Your application.properties should look like this:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand my problem. I would like to handle a form with a spring controller without using spring tag in my JSP files. Spring seems really flexible with using the annotation @ModelAttribute but I don't want using something like <form:form....> in my JSP file.

Comment: Are you trying to use thymeleaf without spring form tags ? not sue it ll work. thats why we suggested jsp combined with jstl and EL.

Comment: By the way @ModelAttribute and jsp's works well without spring form tags

Comment: Do you have an example ? How can I bind the form fields with the form-backing class without using Spring tag ?

Comment: I don't use Thymeleaf in my project

Comment: @Achille_vanhoutte Your answer is not in line with the question asked. Please revisit